# Wireless not working with a RTL8191SEvB

Tags: wireless, ralink

my wireless is not working in Ubuntu 11.10 and it worked fine in 11.04, i've done a fresh install and it detects the wireless but when i try to connect it keeps asking for the WPA key.Can anyone help me? I've tried to download the drivers from the realtek site but i get an error when i do "sudo make" i'm using a 64bit and i've tried the 32bit and nothing solves the problem.

my wireless card: RTL8191SEvB

Comment: Connecting to an unprotected wireless network fails too, but connecting through Bluetooth and my phone's 3G does work, the problem seems to be in the wireless drivers malfunctioning somehow. I can find all the wireless networks and such, but trying to connect just makes the icon in the top left corner blinking and after a minute or so it either disconnects or asks for the password again. Setting the password in the network manager by editing the network info doesn't help either. I hope they patch this bug soon... 3G just isn't enough :S

Answer (score 3):

You have to compile the driver.

Download the latest Linux driver [from Realtek](http://www.realtek.com/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=48&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true#RTL8192SE). Choose the Linux driver for kernel 2.6.35 and above.

Install a few dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Extract all files. In a terminal, execute the following commands:

```
cd into the extracted directory
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rtl8192se
```

Wifi should be working now. In order to keep the wifi working after a reboot, add one line with "rtl8192se" to the /etc/modules file.

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modules
```

Modified from http://michael-peeters.blogspot.com/2011/10/fixing-rtl8191se-wifi-under-ubuntu-1110.html

Answer (score 0):

The "WPA key" is the password protecting your network. Your previous version (11.04) must have been set up to automatically enter the password. All you need to do is enter the password and set Ubuntu up to login automatically.

If you do not remember the password, you will have to connect to the router through an ethernet cable and change the password from there.

I switched too from 11.04 to 11.10. The new (Huawei 173) surfstick did  not work.
What I did: I reinstalled the usb-modeswitch (these are two (by default installed) apps). Then - after waitung a minute or so -- it started working (first asking for the pin).

Comment: thanks i've reset my WPA key in the router and entered it but it dont connects and keeps asking for the WPA key wich i've reset to a new one

Comment: Is the router set up with the *exact* same password you are entering?

Comment: yes, i check it twice, and i've done a copy paste and nothing worked

Comment: Have you made sure both the router and your wireless card are set up for the same encryption? (WPA or WPA2-much better by the way)

Comment: WPA & WPA2 Personal on both

Comment: You normally can only choose *one* on each and they need to be the same.  :)

Comment: it's the WPA2 Personal but still got no connection

Comment: and i am able to connect to the router from windows

Comment: Do you have MAC address filtering enabled? It will not allow you to connect unless you set up your device from the router.

Comment: no i dont have mac address filtering enabled

Comment: If network manager is asking you to authenticate a connection, then you do not need drivers. They are already installed and working. If network manager cannot detect any wireless networks, then one reason may be that the wireless adapter is not working because the drivers are not installed. (I said one reason. There are other reasons). But that is not your situation.

Comment: I have the exact same issue, but on a Broadcom adapter. Connection manager repeatedly asks for the WPA2 password I've triple-checked is correct. Wireless works on Windows and 11.04, no MAC-filtering is enabled. It's apparently a bug in the wireless stack, not on a particular driver.