# How to connect to WiFi from Lubuntu?

Tags: wireless, networking, lubuntu, network-manager

After add the *Manage Networks* icon into the panel, I can see my Wi-Fi network on the list. So I click on the SSID and it prompt for a password. I enter the right *or* wrong password but nothing happens.

The access point is working fine, I have others devices connected to it working properly.

I've tried to compile the *RTL8191SE* driver but they have *syntax errors*.

---

More information:

[`lsmod`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7400499/)

[`dmesg | tail -n 30`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7404773/)

```
$ uname -a
Linux lucio-net 3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 19:11:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lspci -nn | grep 0280
Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8191SEvB Wireless LAN Controller [10ec:8172] (rev 10)

$ nmcli d
DEVICE TYPE             STATE
wlan0  802-11-wireless  disconnected

$ nm-tool
NetworkManager Tool

State: disconnected

- Device: wlan0
Type: 802.11 WiFi
Driver: rtl8192se
State: disconnected
Default: no

Capabilities:

Wireless Properties
 WEP Encryption: yes
 WAP Encryption: yes
 WAP2 Encryption: yes

Wireless Access Points
 [SSID]: Infra, [MAC], Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 100 WPA WPA2
```

Comment: Your `dmesg` output is pretty much just a USB drive being plugged in and then removed. Can you try connecting and immediately post the `dmesg` output again, hopefully to catch the wifi info?

Comment: I use a USB drive to get this output out of the machine. That's why I plug in & out several times. Anyway I updated the output.

Comment: Which version of Lubuntu are you using?

Comment: The last one, 14.04.

Comment: It looks like your card is working, have you tried to reset the router, or change the password on the wifi to see if maybe there is some sort of weird issue there. Have you tried connecting to any other wireless network - or does this happen no matter which network you try to connect to?

Comment: Take a look at this previous question http://askubuntu.com/questions/66872/wireless-not-working-with-a-rtl8191sevb If you are having trouble installing the correct driver can you post the problem here, maybe we can look at it. From this other post it looks like there was a problem with the authentication.

Comment: you sure "managed networks" in the network manager applet?

Comment: In Lubuntu is called that way, I'm sure.

Comment: Doesn't it ask for an encryption code?

Comment: @Lucio - can you have a look at this thread - check carefully that your realtek matches the bug report.  If it is the same - looks like you should launchpad bug report it and ask for the attached 3.14.1 fix to be backported.  You could also try installing the latest 3.14 series kernel as well from the kernel mainline. https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=74541

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure you are using the network manager applet. I would recommend typing `nm-applet` and use that. In case you need a workaround with the command line, you can configure network manager using `nmcli` tool. The syntax for wireless connections is as follows:

```
nmcli dev wifi connect <(B)SSID> [password <password>] [wep-key-type key|phrase] [iface <iface>] [bssid <BSSID>] [name <name>] [--private] [--nowait] [--timeout <timeout>]
```

Just remove the things that you don't need and change the ones that you need. If you don't have a WEP network, just don't use the `wep-key-type` option. This should be enough for a simple WPA/2 connection:

```
nmcli dev wifi connect mynetwork password my-password
```

Comment: The `nmcli` command works perfect, but I would need to type it every time I boot. The `nm-applet` also works great, but I also *need to type it every time I boot*. Any idea in how to stick it there?

Comment: @Lucio add it to the "applications start-up" that Lubuntu has. http://askubuntu.com/a/159011/169736

Comment: @Braiam, Your answer makes no sense. He's using Network Manager. The command he ran already saved the connection. The **whole point** of Network Manager is so you don't have to manually setup hacky startup routines.

Comment: @Cerin I don't see where the problem is. He's using network manager, I'm using *the* network manager tool. What's wrong with that?