# Lubuntu wifi help

Tags: lubuntu

Ok. Here's the basics. ----older laptop, dell 600 . Intel 2200 GB wireless card I believe.  Sees my router, won't take the WPA key. I've done quite a bit of forum browsing and I noticed my channel is set to 0. I have 1-11 available but can't seem to change it. Any ideas would be helpful. Thank you.

sudo iwlist eth1 auth

eth1      Authentication capabilities :
        WPA
        WPA2
        CIPHER-TKIP
        CIPHER-CCMP
          Current TKIP countermeasures : yes
          Current Drop unencrypted : yes
          Current Authentication algorithm :
          Current Receive unencrypted EAPOL : no
          Current Roaming control : yes
          Current Privacy invoked : yes

also ran
sudo iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

eth1      IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:off/any
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated
          Bit Rate:0 kb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   Sensitivity=8/0
          Retry limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

Comment: The question is ?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of this terminal command: sudo iwlist eth1 auth Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, it has been edited.The question is this, Might there be a problem with my card connecting to my router. I currently have Verizon Fios. I know the WPA key is correct.

Answer (score 0):

As someone already said, your question isn't clear. But my two cents would be this: try using nmcli from command line to connect or use wicd tool.

More here on nmcli:
[How to connect to WiFi from Lubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/461384/how-to-connect-to-wifi-from-lubuntu)

More here on wicd:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1998946

Let me know if that helped

Comment: Thanks but I know about connecting through command line. I just can't connect to my wifi. I just put my new phone on my wifi so I know the pw for it is correct. Just my laptop keeps saying wrong pw.

Comment: Look at this, maybe it's relevant: http://askubuntu.com/questions/304460/wifi-only-accepts-passwords-of-5-or-13-characters

Comment: Also, it's just a thought , but does your password have some special characters? Try changing your password through the phone (access the router through 192.168.0.1) and try reconnecting with the new password. Just a suggestion